# Windows 8 not detecting Wi-Fi

Tags: networking, windows-8, wireless-networking, home-networking, wifi-configuration

My PC is not detecting the signal of the wireless router in the room. My roommates can use it with no issues. My PC is showing other Wi-Fi signals, but not the Wi-Fi of my own room. I have tried troubleshooting – I have tried restarting the router and the PC several times – but of no use. I have to use a LAN cable to connect to the Internet. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: did you switch off your wifi and switch on?

Comment: Routers can be configured not to advertise their SSID. If your roommates have previously registered with the network, they _don't need_ the router to advertize itself (they already know the SSID). You,on the other hand, won't see it. Check router settings. Also be sure that your computer supports both the frequency band (2.4 or 5 GHz) and the 802.11 flavour (like, b, g, n, ac, ...). Network cards do not necessarily support all of them, and routers are often configured not to use all of them (since mixed mode runs at the slowest mode that anyone uses).

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same issue on my Toshiba laptop after a windows update. I had to un-install the wifi driver under device manager,  un-install all the vendor related software and let windows use the default inbuilt driver for wifi.

Comment: did it fix the problem?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like a weird driver problem to me

**See here to reinstall WiFi drivers specifically**

[How to reinstall Wireless drivers - Wikihow](http://m.wikihow.com/Reinstall-Wireless-Drivers)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.